# facebook invite notification not working

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$output = '<script src="'.$base_url.'/'.$modulePath.'/fblib/fb_all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
appId:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
cookie:true, 
status:true,
frictionlessRequests:true,
xfbml:true
});
function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
    FB.ui({ method: "apprequests", 
   message: "Your display message here."});
}
```

';
    $output .= 'Facebook Invite';
    echo $output;

I am using above code to invite the friends to join the website. When I invite a friend through FaceBook invite popup then invited user gets the notification on facebook browser view. But that user didn't get notification the facebook app. 
I am using facebook app v2.2 version along with canvas configuration over the app.

Any idea for this. Your help will be appreciable!

Thanks

Comment: App invites will only show up on platforms that you have your app set up for. If you don’t have an Android version of your app, the invite will not be shown on Android devices.

Comment: Notifications are not coming on Iphone Facebook App as well. We are using above code for facebook user invite on our website.  We have created a facebook app for this. Problem is we receive notification on facebook website for invitation send through website to a facebook user. However the same notification doesn't show up on facebook app.

Comment: _“I am using above code to invite the friends to join the website”_ – that is only allowed if your app is a game with a _playable_ canvas implementation anyway. For simple external websites, you can not use invite requests.